# Merging branches in TFS

Tags: team-foundation-server

We are on a project using Microsoft Team Foundation Server for source control and have run in to some issues.

We have a "Main" branch that has been branched out to another branch "Child" which we have been working on for a while.

Now we want to merge back the "Child" into "Main" the trouble is that almost no files gets included in the merge. If I pick "Compare" between the branches it says 74 files have changed. But then when I try to use the merge command only one file appear in the "Pending changes".

Anyone have any ideas why this might happen? It seems the TFS:s merging/branching capabilities are very limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things that might be causing this.

Make sure you have the latest version of both branches in your local workspace. If you've got an old version of the child branch then TFS will not recognise the changes on the server. This is because all changes (including merges) are done on your local machine before being committed to the server.

If you've attempted a merge, unchecked files from the pending changes, and then checked in the merge. You've just told TFS to ignore those changes (seems stupid I know). If this is the case then you need to use the "tf merge /force" command from the command prompt "tf merge /?" will show you the full syntax of the merge command